# DotNetREST Client: System.Net.WebException - Es konnte kein SSL/TLS Kanal aufgebaut werden

Tags: c#, .net, rest, ssl, tls1.2

Ich habe ein Problem einen REST Service mit einer einfachen DotNet Applikation aufzurufen. Ich habe das DotNet Framework 4.7.2 verwendet. Nachdem das nicht funktioniert hat habe ich auf dem gleichen Rechner mit Chrome den WebService aufgerufen und das funktioniert. Dann habe ich auf das Schloss geklickt und die Zertifikate der verwendeten Zertifikatskette exportiert und diese danach im Code importiert.

Ich bekomme aber immer noch diese Expeption, dass kein SSL/TLS Kanal etabliert werden konnte.

English :
I have a problem calling a REST service with a simple DotNet application. I used the DotNet Framework 4.7.2. After that didn't work, I called the WebService on the same computer with Chrome and it worked. Then I clicked on the lock and exported the certificates of the certificate chain used and then imported them in the code.

But I still get this expectation that no SSL / TLS channel could be established.

```
    // Create a Web-Request to the ETR dispatcher
    HttpWebRequest req;
    req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://serviceurl/endpoint/healthCheck");

    // The path to the ROOT, SUB and App certificates.
    string rootCert = @"C:\Users\...\Desktop\_work\root.cer";
    string subCert  = @"C:\Users\...\Desktop\_work\sub.cer";
    string appCert  = @"C:\Users\...\Desktop\_work\app.cer";

    // Load the certificates into an X509Certificate objects.
    X509Certificate2 cert1 = new X509Certificate2(rootCert);
    X509Certificate2 cert2 = new X509Certificate2(subCert);
    X509Certificate2 cert3 = new X509Certificate2(appCert);


    // Defined properties for the Web-Request
    req.Method = "GET";
    req.MediaType = "HTTP/1.1";
    req.ContentType = "application/json";
    req.UserAgent = "Example Client";

    // Add the three certificates to this request
    req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert1);
    req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert2);
    req.ClientCertificates.Add(cert3);

    // Ensure that TLS 1.2 is used
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    // Send Web-Request and receive a Web-Response
    HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    // ==> System.Net.WebException {“Die Anfrage wurde abgebrochen: Es konnte kein 
    //                               geschützter SSL/TLS-Kanal erstelle werden.”}
     

    // Translate data from the Web-Response to a string
    Stream dataStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(dataStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    string response = streamreader.ReadToEnd();
    
    streamreader.Close();
```

Comment: You might want to translate your question to english. Since your code is commented in english it looks like as if you are able to do it.

Comment: The following line need to be moved to beginning of the code : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: SO is an English site. Please post your question in English. While there are language-specific sites like `pt.stackoverflow.com`, ru, es, there's no German site because there's little demand for it

Comment: In .NET 4.7.2 the OS's TLS settings are used by default. In all *supported* OSs that's TLS1.2. Which OS are you targeting? If you use an old OS you probably need to patch it. There were several duplicate questions 3-4 years ago as all online services started demanding at least TLS1.2

Comment: Did you load certificates when using Chrome?  If code works with Chrome there is not reason to add certificates with c#.  Are you an Admin?  Did you run code with VS?  Try running in VS by right click VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: @jdweng

thanks for your 1st comment. After moving the code part prior object creation, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, that I haven't used English. It was something like automation, that I wrote in german.

But the issue is solved without loading/importing the three needed certificates.

Thanks to JDWENG, he stated the setup of the protocol version to Tls1.2 should be moved to the beginning.

I assumed that I have to set up the protocol prior to the Webservice Call, but obviously, it affects the creation of the WevRequest Object.

After I moved it in front of the object creation, everything worked. The code part with the import of the 3 certificates had no effect so I deleted this.

thanks to all...